# Error adding legend to plot

Tags: matlab, plot, format, legend, figure

i would like to add a legend to my plot. So far so nice! it has always worked but now i face an error.

My code for the plotting function is the following:

```
function [  ] = plot_mti_IV( Bus_indizes, Bus_voltages,new_results, names )

    global Timeslot

     m={'-','--',':','-','--',':','-.','-*','-^','-.','-*','-^'};

    Timeslot_temp=[1:1:Timeslot(end)];  
    name_index=find(Bus_voltages==1);   %Find index of depicted Variable

    %Initialise legend
    words=['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(1)) names{name_index(1)}] 
    words=[words ;['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(1)) names{name_index(1)}]] 

    num_Bus=length(Bus_indizes);
    colors = distinguishable_colors(num_Bus); %distinguishable_colors.m: Function from Mathworks File Exchange. See license for Copyright!

   for i=1:length(name_index)   %for number of chosen variables

            for j=1:num_Bus  %plot this value for all chosen busses

                if j==1

                   plot_data=new_results{i,1}(Timeslot_temp,Bus_indizes(j));   %collect data to be plotted in array 
                   plot(plot_data,m{i},'Color',colors(j,:) );
                   hold on
                   xlim([Timeslot(1) (Timeslot(end)+Timeslot(end)*0.05)]);     %Adjustment, so that legend does not cover graph
                   hold on

                   xlabel('Time');
                   ylabel('Voltage');                                          

                else 

                   words= [words ; ['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(j)) names{name_index(i)} ]];
                   plot_data=new_results{i,1}(Timeslot_temp,Bus_indizes(j));   %collect data to be plotted in array 
                   plot(plot_data,m{i},'Color',colors(j,:) );
                   hold on

                end
            end      
   end

   legend(words); %Add legend to graph

 end
```

I get an error

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in legend (line 194)
    elseif narg > 0 && ~ischar(varargin{1}) && ...
```

when I execute `legend(words)`.

Before the expression `legend(words)`, `words` has the format:

```
words = 

    'Bus'    '1'    'VBN Voltage Angle'
    'Bus'    '4'    'VBN Voltage Angle'
    'Bus'    '2'    'VBN Voltage Angle'
    'Bus'    '2'    'VCN Voltage Angle'
```

I cannot comprehend this error and would be very glad for your help!

Hi, ahh okay! didnt know that i need an 1xN matrix...@Ander Biguri: yes, this shall be my first legend entry exactly!  here i will post an example that behaves just like the Code above:

```
[ output_args ] = test_plot(  )

figure
Timeslot=[2:1:7]

Bus_indizes=[1,2,3,5]

Bus_voltages=[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]


new_results=magic(12)

names=cell(1,12);
names{1,1}={'VAN Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,2}={'VBN Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,3}={'VCN Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,4}={'VAN Voltage Angle'};
names{1,5}={'VBN Voltage Angle'};
names{1,6}={'VCN Voltage Angle'};
names{1,7}={'V1 Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,8}={'V2 Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,9}={'V0 Voltage Magnitude'};
names{1,10}={'V1 Voltage Angle'};
names{1,11}={'V2 Voltage Angle'};
names{1,12}={'V0 Voltage Angle'};

     m={'-','--',':','-','--',':','-.','-*','-^','-.','-*','-^'};

    Timeslot_temp=[1:1:Timeslot(end)];  %Array containing all time instants from absolute Beginning of simulation (not necessarily the first value of the timeslot) till the end of the timeslot
    name_index=find(Bus_voltages==1);   %Find index of depicted Variable

    %Initialise words
    words=['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(1)) names{name_index(1)}] 
    words=[words ;['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(1)) names{name_index(1)}]] 

    num_Bus=length(Bus_indizes);
    colors = distinguishable_colors(num_Bus); %distinguishable_colors.m: Function from Mathworks File Exchange. See license for Copyright!

   for i=1:length(name_index)   %for number of chosen variables

            for j=1:num_Bus  %plot this value for all chosen busses, color is changed for every bus

                if j==1

                   plot_data=new_results(Timeslot_temp,Bus_indizes(j));   %collect data to be plotted in array 
                   plot(plot_data,m{i},'Color',colors(j,:) );
                   hold on
                   xlim([Timeslot(1) (Timeslot(end)+Timeslot(end)*0.05)]);     %Adjustment, so that legend does not cover graph
                   hold on

                   xlabel('Time');
                   ylabel('Voltage');                                          %Label y axis with name of the chosen variable

                else 

                   words= [words ; ['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(j)) names{name_index(i)} ]];
                   plot_data=new_results(Timeslot_temp,Bus_indizes(j));   %collect data to be plotted in array 
                   plot(plot_data,m{i},'Color',colors(j,:) );
                   hold on

                end
            end      
   end

   legend(words); %Add legend to graph

 end
```

Comment: `legend` does not accept  2D cells or matrices of strings. You need to have a 1xN matrix. What is the expected behavior here? Do you want the first legend to be `Bus 1 VBN Voltage Angle`? Also, Can you post some data to run it?

Comment: You say it has always worked. Did it work in this context? If so, can you post the last code that worked and what you want legend to display?

Comment: Hi, ahh okay! didnt know that i need an 1xN matrix...@Ander Biguri: yes, this shall be my first legend entry exactly!  here i will post an example that behaves just like the Code above:

Comment: The error itself complains about using `&&` and `||`, try to set them to `&` and `|` i.e. single instances.

Comment: i dont use those logical operators in the code as you see above! i cannot explain it to me!

Comment: Does anybody have an idea about how to realize it somehow? it seems to me that this is a quite common problem since one often faces a variable number of variables to be plotted and to be shown in a legend....unfortunately i couldnt find a solution so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i now solved the problem by using the function strjoin:

```
words={};

temp=['Bus' num2str(Bus_indizes(j)) names{variables_index(i)} ];
words{end+1}=strjoin(temp); 

legend(words);
```